# Getting Response from python script in Node API

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python script which deals with image, reading and extracting text from image. Now i have a requirement where i have to call that python script from node js. My issue is how do i get the response from python script in node ?

Python script :-

```
response = image_to_dict('test.jpg', bucketname)
detections = dict_to_detections(response)
entities = list_to_entities(detections.lines)
print("Payer is {payerName}".format(payerName=extractPayer(entities.orgs, 
response)))
print("Member name is 
{memberName}".format(memberName=extractMemberName(entities.persons)))
print("Member ID is 
{memberId}".format(memberId=extractMemberId(detections.lines)))
```

Node js :-

```
    var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
 PythonShell.run('test.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Now i need what i print in python script e.g Payer Name as response in node js.
Any input would be greatfull.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With error you need to pass another parameter in the function which will give you array of messages printed in the shell script.

```
PythonShell.run('test.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

More: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

Answer (score 0):

as stated in [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#runscript-options-callback) you just need to provide another argument in your callback

```
PythonShell.run('script.py', function (err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(results);
});
```

> Runs the Python script and invokes callback with the results. The
>   callback contains the execution error (if any) as well as an array of
>   messages emitted from the Python script.